# Numerically finding impulse response from a wave equation

Tags: impulse-response, numerical-algorithms

I'm developing a song synthesizer (like Yamaha's Vocaloid). I decided to mimic the acoustics of human speech. I modeled the space between articulators as a [solid of revolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solid_of_revolution), and came up with the following PDE:

$$
(PA)_{tt} = c^2 (P_x A)_x
$$
where $P$ is air pressure (difference to the atmosphere; unknown), $A$ is cross-sectional area of the solid (known), and $c$ is the speed of sound.

By being a wave equation, I need two boundary conditions and two initial conditions.

Discretizing $x \in [0, 26 × c/F_s]$ by $m \in [0, 26]$ and $t \in [0,1]$ by $n \in [0, 44099 = F_s - 1]$, since I'm finding the impulse response:

$$
P[0,n] = \delta[n]
$$

Since the vocal cord is modeled by a vibrating closed end of the solid:

$$
P_x[0,n] = 0
$$

Since there were initially no sound, apart from at the vocal cord:

$$
P[m,0] = \delta[m]
\\
P_t[m,0] = 0
$$

And what I really need is $P[26,n]$.

I tried using finite difference method, but due to the initial conditions, the solution becomes $P = 0$. This doesn't make sense, and I think this means I must make the grid finer, interpolating the $\delta$. But for which, $x$ or $t$?